# Term for public holiday that isn't the same date every year?

Tags: dates

I just need the term for a public holiday or event that changes it's date every year. So for example Christmas is always on December 25 but Labour Day will change so does Easter every year.

TIA

Comment: Easter is traditionally called a _movable feast_ (in the old sense of 'religious festival', not a meal).

Answer (score 3):

The traditional phrase for these is a [moveable feast](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/movable-feast.html), but I'm not sure that anybody still uses the term in its literal sense.

Comment: what if it's not easter/feast what if it's labour day or some other event?

Comment: I know of no term for it.